# Windows Media Center update schedule?

Tags: windows-media-center

When my computer is sleeping, sometime it does open to download TV schedules and do not turn back in sleep mode. But the problem is that it does it in the middle of the night. How can I setup Windows Media Center to update only in the day?

*In the menu I have found a way to do it manually instead of automaticly but not an option to set a range of time...

Answer (score 2):

Go to the start menu and type "Task Scheduler"

Click on Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Media Center

Double click on "mcupdate_scheduled"

Here you can change what time it starts and whether or not it wakes up the computer or not

Comment: +1 but in the history I do not see any Actions done in the night and I know sometime this has wake up me in the middle of the night. +1 but I'll wait to accept.

Comment: It still continue to wake up in the middle of the night argg